Dirac's quantisation condition and non-quantised charge
After some time searching for a convincing demonstration of the Dirac quantisation condition, I've finally come across not one but three of them in David Tong's book: Gauge Theory. Nonetheless, it all boils down to the product of both electric ($e$) and magnetic ($g$) charges being quantized:
$$eg=2\pi\hbar n, \ \ \ n\in \mathbb{Z}$$
What I don't understand is why this statement implies both electric and magnetic charge should be quantised simultaneously. Strictly speaking, it could also mean that only electric charge is quantised and magnetic charge isn't, or the other way around. Why do we accept that Dirac's quantisation condition implies both charges are quantised simultaneously?

The identity $e g = 2\pi n$ (setting $\hbar=1$) has to hold for ALL electric and magnetic charges. Let $e_0$ be the smallest electric charge and let $g_0$ be the smallest magnetic charge (smallest in magnitude). Then, the equation implies that all electric and magnetic charges must satisfy
$$
e_i g_0 = 2\pi n_i , \qquad e_0 g_i = 2\pi m_i
$$
Consequently,
$$
e_i = \frac{2\pi}{g_0} n_i , \qquad g_i = \frac{2\pi}{e_0} m_i
$$
Thus, all $e_i$ and $g_i$ are quantized.

This is correct as long as you add the extra assumption that there exists a smallest (in magnitude) non-zero electric charge. If (for example) all real charges are allowed then it doesn't work (because there isn't a smallest positive number).

I suppose I am assuming that there are finitely many charged particles in the theory.

Are you correct that the identity has to hold for all charges in the way you write? It has to hold for combined systems but that leads to equations like $e_i g_i = 2\pi n_i$ not $e_i g_0 = 2\pi n_i$.

@ors yes, it has to hold for ALL charges, including the fundamental charges.

Do you have an argument as to why?

@ors - it’s literally Dirac’s argument that is being discussed here. You should read up on that.

Dirac's argument doesn't say what you claim in this answer though (at least the version I'm familiar with). Dirac's argument works for all combinations of charges you can make from whatever fundamental particles exist. In particular if you have a particle with a non-zero electric $e_0$ and magnetic charge $g_0$ then it doesn't necessarily follow that you can make a composite system with charges $e_i$ and $g_0$ for any other charge $e_i$ that exists.

@ors - I don't think Dirac's argument has anything to do with composite systems. Roughly, the argument goes like this - Suppose there exists a magnetic charge $g$ and an electric charge $e$ (these could be fundamental charges or composite, whatever). The magnetic charge is attached to a Dirac string. Moving the electric charge around the Dirac string, one picks up an Aharonov-Bohm phase $e^{ieg}$. However, the Dirac string should be undetectable, so we must have $eg = 2\pi n$
